# Microsoft Graph API fetch user collection from Group members using java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I need to fetch the users from a group with certain ID. For this one there is a code snippet in the official documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java

```
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

LinkedList<Option> requestOptions = new LinkedList<Option>();
requestOptions.add(new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual"));
requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$search", "displayName:Pr"));

UserCollectionPage user = graphClient.groups("{id}").members().microsoft.graph.user()
    .buildRequest( requestOptions )
    .select("displayName,id")
    .orderBy("displayName")
    .get();
```

As can be seen from the above sample given, there is a chain call after members(). method, however although I use the latest version from maven central repository, .microsoft() method does not exist and isn't resolving to anything.
If I use members().buildRequest().get() then it brings me an another directory instance but not the usercollectionpage list. How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the example may be an old example, actually you can use a different method based on the object you want instead of `members()` the `membersAsUser()`  actually the memberAsUser add the path microsoft.graph.user like this way

```
//microsoft ghraph source code
@Nonnull
public UserCollectionRequestBuilder membersAsUser() {
    return new UserCollectionRequestBuilder(getRequestUrlWithAdditionalSegment("members") + "/microsoft.graph.user", getClient(), null);
}
```

so the example with be like this way

```
UserCollectionPage user = graphClient.groups("{id}").membersAsUser()
                .buildRequest( requestOptions )
                .select("displayName,id")
                .orderBy("displayName")
                .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the groups endpoint

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

LinkedList<Option> requestOptions = new LinkedList<Option>();
requestOptions.add(new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual"));
GroupCollectionPage group = graphClient.users({id}).memberOf().microsoft.graph.group()
.buildRequest( requestOptions )
.filter("startswith(displayName, 'in')")
.orderBy("displayName")
.get();
```

I had to work around it since .microsoft() method does not exist and isn't resolving to anything.

```
  final GroupCollectionPage userGroups = _appClient.users({id})
            .memberOfAsGroup()
            .buildRequest(requestOptions)
            .select("displayName,id,mail")
            .filter("startswith(displayName, 'c')")
            .orderBy("displayName")
            .get();
```